# Convergence in the Implicit function theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

Possibly a dumb question. In the implicit function theorem we take $F\in C^k(\Lambda\times U, Y)$ with $k\geq 1$, $Y$ is a Banach space, and $\Lambda, U$ are open subsets of Banach spaces $T,X$. If $F(\lambda^*,u^*) = 0$ and $F_u(\lambda^*,u^*)$ is an invertible linear map then there exists neighbourhoods $\Theta$ and $V$ of $\lambda^*$ and $u^*$ and a map $g\in C^k(\Theta,U^*)$ such that $$F(\lambda, g(\lambda))=0$$ 
 for all $\lambda\in\Theta$. What type of convergence does $g(\lambda)\to u^*$ have? For example, if we take $X$ to be $$H_r^1=\{u:\int_0^\infty (u^2+(u')^2)rdr <\infty\}$$
does $g(\lambda)\to u^*$ uniformly? In norm? Just pointwise? By uniformly I mean $|g(\lambda)-u^*|<\epsilon$ for all $r$ when $|\lambda-\lambda^*|<\delta$

Comment: What do you mean by uniform vs. pointwise? The convergence is in whatever norm the Banach space is supplied with. Maybe an example that illustrates the confusion would be useful?

Comment: I'm dealing with a problem right now where $X$ is essentially $H^1$ on the positive real line. So convergence in norm does not imply uniform convergence, which I guess answers the question I wanted to ask.